# Modified Boole's Inequality - $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i) - \frac{2}{n} \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 \leq n} P(A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2})$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove the inequality (a) $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i) - \frac{2}{n} \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 \leq n} P(A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2})$.

A previous result that can be utilized in the proof is (b) $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i) - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} P(A_i \cap A_{i+1})$.

My strategy has been to show that the right hand side of (a) is greater than the right hand side of (b) using the Inclusion-Exclusion principle, but to no avail. Additionally I have no idea where the $\frac{2}{n}$ term comes from. What am I missing?

Comment: This is cute!  The left hand side does not depend on the ordering of the sets $A_i$ but the right hand side does.

Comment: Hint : How many terms do you have in addition by taking the sum  with $i_1<i_2$ indexing rather than just $i$

Comment: @EDX There are $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ terms, but the probability of each term could be different so I don't see how that cancels out the $\frac{2}{n}$?

Comment: Yes but knowing the ordering of the $A_i$ helps

Comment: @EDX By ordering do you mean the order of the $A_i$ as subsets of one another or the order of the terms in the inclusion-exclusion principle? I've tried rearranging the terms around in summations for both (a) and (b) but I'm not getting any closer.

Comment: When getting $A_i \cap A_{i+1}$ for a fixed $i$ you also know that you will have the same probability with all the $k<i+1$ and $A_k \cap A_{i+1}$. Can you see further from here ?

Comment: @EDX I'm sorry, I'm still struggling. If $A_k \cap A_{i+1}$ has the same probability for each $k<i+1$, and we let $a_{i+1} = P(A_k \cap A_{i+1})$, then I get the two sums being subtracted as $\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{2(i-1)}{n} a_i$ and $\sum_{i=2}^n a_i$ respectively. I can't seem to show that the former is necessarily greater than the latter (and thus that the RHS of (a) is greater than (b)) for the purpose of the inequality. I also don't know why we can assume that for a fixed $i$ we have the same probabilities of $A_k \cap A_{i+1}$ when $k<i+1$

Comment: If $A_i \subseteq A_{i+1}$ there is no problem for the second part. Honesty for the first point I doubt you can reach it from your (b).